# Return a value from within .on() .once() call in Firebase for use in .then()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I am trying to understand the return value from within a firebase `ref.on('value'` or `ref.once('value'` call;
so I can use the returned value from there in a `.then(` that follows.
It does not seem to matter what I try to return from the
`ref.on('value', snap => { return 'Test Text or whatever'}` for example, I always get an object where `.node_.value_` will be what ever was the `.val()` from the firebase call.
Explanation of this behaviour will be appreciated (at the moment I am writing untidy and convoluted code to get the job done and would like to avoid this).

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('myAddress/etc..');
ref.once('value', snap => {
  o0 = snap.val()
  console.log('In the once o0:')
  console.log(o0) // works perfectly
  // return 'Test text' // does not return the text
  // return o0 // does not return o0
}).then( in0 => {
  console.log(in0)
  console.log(`In the first then in0.node_.value_ is:`)
  console.log(in0.node_.value_)
  return in0.node_.value_
}).then( in1 => {
  console.log(`In the second then input was:`)
  console.log(in1) // here I begin to get what I want the value from: in0.node_.value_
  return 'Some text from custom then'
}).then( in0 => {
  console.log('In the third then input was:')
  console.log(in0) // this prints: 'Some text from custom then', as my sanity check
})
```

I am trying to really understand what is going on here so the that code I write is sensible.
I can write the functionality within the `on('value...' call but this will not work in other parts of the app I am working on.
Appreciate an explanation or even a link to where this is explained in the Firebase docs.

Comment: You're not using the value that is returned from `once` anywhere.

Comment: If you are referring to the value of `snap` I use it to get  `o0` then console.log `o0` ; question is can I return something else out of the `once` call. That I can't do and can't understand why not. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To use `ref.once('value')` as a promise, you should omit the second argument and go straight to the `.then`:

```
ref.once('value').then(snap => {
  o0 = snap.val()
  console.log('In the once o0:')
  console.log(o0) // works perfectly
  return o0 // does indeed return o0
}).then( in0 => {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Now the `snap.val()` is undefined, hence the returned value is also undefined. Note that the `snap` object here is completely different from the `snap` from `ref.once('value', snap =>`. There is no  function `.val()` in the prototype. Thanks

Comment: [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once) suggests this should work.